# Combining usage of Terraform's zipmap, maps, and lists

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hcl

I have two different scenarios, one with public subnets and one with private.

For both, I would like to apply some combination of `for`-loop and `zipmask` to have a single map object. You can assume I have checked the ordering of the two input maps/lists and that they are align.

Using the public-subnet as the first example, I have one cidr for each user:

```
pub_cidr_map = {
  "user2" = "10.0.8.0/21"
  "user4" = "10.0.24.0/21"
  "user1" = "10.0.0.0/21"
  "user3" = "10.0.16.0/21"
}

pub_id_list = [
  "subnet-666666662ee6f3442",
  "subnet-6666666696b92d895",
  "subnet-66666666cbaa4bfb3",
  "subnet-6666666655a09d064",
]
```

I would like this to look like this so I can access both values with a single key:

```
pub_lookup_map = {
  "user2" = ["10.0.8.0/21", "subnet-666666662ee6f3442"]
  "user4" = ["10.0.24.0/21", "subnet-6666666696b92d895"]
  "user1" = ["10.0.0.0/21", "subnet-66666666cbaa4bfb3"]
  "user3" = ["10.0.16.0/21", "subnet-6666666655a09d064"]
}
```

I'd also like to accomplish something similar with my private subets, which are apportioned two-per-user:

```
priv_cidr_map = {
  "user1" = [
    "10.0.96.0/20",
    "10.0.112.0/20",
  ]
  "user2" = [
    "10.0.160.0/20",
    "10.0.176.0/20",
  ]
  "user3" = [
    "10.0.64.0/20",
    "10.0.80.0/20",
  ]
  "user4" = [
    "10.0.128.0/20",
    "10.0.144.0/20",
  ]
}

priv_id_list = [
  "subnet-666666662f611f9a5",
  "subnet-6666666689f1eff5e",
  "subnet-66666666a3fe6efb9",
  "subnet-66666666faf4a62a8",
  "subnet-666666668f1442700",
  "subnet-66666666328a4b134",
  "subnet-666666661b147a933",
  "subnet-666666661ce02c330"
]
```

I would like this to look like

```
priv_lookup_map = {
  "user1" = [
    ["10.0.96.0/20","subnet-666666662f611f9a5"]
    ["10.0.112.0/20","subnet-6666666689f1eff5e"]
  ]
  "user2" = [
    ["10.0.160.0/20","subnet-66666666a3fe6efb9"]
    ["10.0.176.0/20","subnet-66666666faf4a62a8"]
  ]
  "user3" = [
    ["10.0.64.0/20","subnet-666666668f1442700"]
    ["10.0.80.0/20","subnet-66666666328a4b134"]
  ]
  "user4" = [
    ["10.0.128.0/20","subnet-666666661b147a933"]
    ["10.0.144.0/20","subnet-666666661ce02c330"]
  ]
}
```

I am open to any other structures someone might think are useful; the use case here is to provision subnets and EIPs as part of a separate, stateful deployment of a VPC prior to the deployment of the resources (like EC2, RDS) that will reside within these ranges.

Comment: "You can assume I have checked the ordering of the two input maps/lists and that they are align" - In Terraform maps are unordered (like hashmaps), so when you iterate over them, the original order will not be preserved. In fact, the keys will be sorted in lexicographical order: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/does-map-sort-keys/12056

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi When I check the values of the subnet IDs (eg, in `pub_id_list`) in the AWS console against the CIDRs they represent (eg, `pub_cidr_map`) the two align, at least on the 4 or 5 deployments I've done so far.  I also have a very basic attempt at this with `zipmap(keys(var.pub_cidrs), module.vpc.public_subnets)` that seems to also align the IDs with their correct CIDRs so far...that said, I am 100% open to using the keys to "lookup" the correct entry to append...

Comment: I've just tried `zipmap(keys(var.pub_cidr_map), var.pub_id_list)` according to your input. The result will map `user1` with `subnet-666666662ee6f3442`, `user2` with `subnet-6666666696b92d895`, etc. which is not correct.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi I sanitized the input names and IDs manually on this site, which is probably having an effect.  That's why I said you can assume I've checked this ordering issue and not to worry about it.  I'm also slightly confused by `Terraform maps are unordered` versus `sorted in lexicographical order` - if both maps are in lexigraphical order isn't this a non-issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not guarantee that this solution is correct, I will share my attempt anyway hoping it might be helpful.

For the public subnets:

```
locals {
  pub_lookup_map = {for key, value in zipmap(keys(var.pub_cidr_map), var.pub_id_list) : key => [var.pub_cidr_map[key], value] }
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
pub = {
  "user1" = [
    "10.0.0.0/21",
    "subnet-666666662ee6f3442",
  ]
  "user2" = [
    "10.0.8.0/21",
    "subnet-6666666696b92d895",
  ]
  "user3" = [
    "10.0.16.0/21",
    "subnet-66666666cbaa4bfb3",
  ]
  "user4" = [
    "10.0.24.0/21",
    "subnet-6666666655a09d064",
  ]
}
```

The problem with this output is that, as I noted in the comments, the iteration over a the keys of a map happens in a lexicographical order. This means that `user1` will be mapped to the first entry from `pub_id_list`, `user2` to the second entry, etc. Even if you are suggesting in the comments that "I've checked this ordering issue and not to worry about it", please double check this solution before using it.

For the private subnets:

```
locals {
  cidr_subnet_id = zipmap(flatten(values(var.priv_cidr_map)), var.priv_id_list)

  priv_lookup_map = {for key, value in var.priv_cidr_map: key => [ for cidr in value: [cidr, local.cidr_subnet_id[cidr]]]}
}
```

Please note, that I'm using an intermediary local variable to make my code readable. The value for `cidr_subnet_id` will be:

```
cidr_subnet_id = {
  "10.0.112.0/20" = "subnet-6666666689f1eff5e"
  "10.0.128.0/20" = "subnet-666666661b147a933"
  "10.0.144.0/20" = "subnet-666666661ce02c330"
  "10.0.160.0/20" = "subnet-66666666a3fe6efb9"
  "10.0.176.0/20" = "subnet-66666666faf4a62a8"
  "10.0.64.0/20" = "subnet-666666668f1442700"
  "10.0.80.0/20" = "subnet-66666666328a4b134"
  "10.0.96.0/20" = "subnet-666666662f611f9a5"
}
```

This is essentially a map between the CIDR and the subnet id. Apparently, this works correctly, because the keys from the `priv_lookup_map` are in lexicographical order when provided. I think this somewhat answers your question in the comments for "if both maps are in lexigraphical order isn't this a non-issue?"

The output for `priv_lookup_map` will be:

```
priv = {
  "user1" = [
    [
      "10.0.96.0/20",
      "subnet-666666662f611f9a5",
    ],
    [
      "10.0.112.0/20",
      "subnet-6666666689f1eff5e",
    ],
  ]
  "user2" = [
    [
      "10.0.160.0/20",
      "subnet-66666666a3fe6efb9",
    ],
    [
      "10.0.176.0/20",
      "subnet-66666666faf4a62a8",
    ],
  ]
  "user3" = [
    [
      "10.0.64.0/20",
      "subnet-666666668f1442700",
    ],
    [
      "10.0.80.0/20",
      "subnet-66666666328a4b134",
    ],
  ]
  "user4" = [
    [
      "10.0.128.0/20",
      "subnet-666666661b147a933",
    ],
    [
      "10.0.144.0/20",
      "subnet-666666661ce02c330",
    ],
  ]
}
```